# Call stored Procedure from a shell script

Tags: windows, sql-server-2008, shell

I would like to call a SQL-Script from a normal console script, how can i do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the [SQLcmd Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)